# Dynamic navigation mesh generation algorithm

Tags: javascript, navmesh

I'm working on a 2D game (top down / zelda like view)

I'm struggling with navigation mesh generation, in complex scenarios my homemade algorithm is lost and too slow...

I would really love to see a detailed explanation of Hertel-Melhorn Algorithm (if you have any ressources). I'm open to suggestions for other good algorithms, as long as I can process round and square obstacles.

My map is randomly generated and obstacles can be added anytime.

- I don't want to use a grid system, my entities are positionned freely.
- My map is big so I can't store precalculated paths / I just need pathfinding to be efficient

I'm working with Javascript, I can't use c++ library like detour/recast

---

### Edit

I am looking for serious documentation of fast triangulation algorithm

If I understand the process of navmesh generation :

1. Input walkable area(s) as polygons
2. triangulation of walkable area
3. (Optionnal) merge triangles to big convex polygons
4. Output a node graph

Comment: How exactly do you find grid systems to be a problem with freely positioned objects?

Comment: I can't flag the question because of the bounty, but a possible duplicate with http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31208/how-can-i-generate-a-2d-navigation-mesh-in-a-dynamic-environment-at-runtime.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 my question is more about the HM algorithm, already saw this question but it did not help.
WilliamMariager: obstacles and moving objects won't "snap" to a grid and I could have round objects (transformed to pseudo-round polygons). At the end, I want to generate a graph of convex polygons, but I need a fast-triangulation algorithm to achieve this

Comment: Navigation and how things move visually are two different things. The result of navigation on a grid doesn't mean your object has to move in a gridlike manner. Just has to move from one node to the next.

Comment: but you can only deal with horizontal and vertical segments, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this answer won't be satisfactory for you.

1. You say you have obstacles, and if i understand right, these would be *inside* a surrounding, large polygon? The Hertel-Melhorn algorithm works on a single polygon only, not on a polygon holding polygons inside. Additionally, having multiple obstacles (polygons) for partitioning on the outside creates a "compare each polygon to each other" situation. And that sounds very exponential = expensive.
2. You say you want to include round obstacles. Seen from outside, a circle is concave, implying that *each* of it's vertices is a partition point, and the same of course goes for each other round obstacle as well. It seems this pretty much nullifies the advantage of partitioning in the first place?

A bad path for the logic may be that you want to first create a large, full data set for the entire scenario, and apply navmesh thinking on that - have that as a basis for all objects' all navigation, and maybe for a loger period of time, while yet having moving (or at least appearing/disappearing) obstacles. As partitioning is a "global" thing, each minor change somewhere would cause an entire arena re-partitioning?

Perhaps it would still be more sensible to apply local-to-the-moving-object pathfinding grids (small, isolated ones) with high granularity, such that only take into consideration what is relevant for (very nearby to) the object in question, at it's very current position and only for the next few moments. And then have a larger scale similar, for general (main goal) movement directions?

Also to note: Moving objects do often not have to follow grid points (or node points) exactly. This depends on what they are. You can still make them dislike turning, react slowly, aim n points ahead, calculate curves/polynoms to follow in the grid, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your try. I'm aware circle being a problem, that's why I turn them into polygons. I had a look at https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/FastTriangulation.pdf and I am looking for the outer tirangulation algorithm. My map is divided into chunks and each one is responsible of maintaining its navmesh. This way I have multiple levels of pathfinding and I can avoid generating a huge navmesh each time something is added.

Comment: It's not as much the circle (which IS a polygon) being the problem, but that your polygon is not simple - you want to triangulate between multiple polygons. BUT: Would it be acceptable to merge any obstacle polygon with the surrounding "arena" polygon, each time one appears (and reverse as it disappears), so that you still end up with one simple polygon for that chunk? This would simply mean finding the closest vertex in the "full" poly. THEN the HM algorithm (which is rather simple to implement) would do the job you want. You'd possibly have to number each obstacle, for chain breaking issues.

Comment: I made a pen to show different use case : http://codepen.io/VincentCharpentier/full/bpMYVd/ I don't see how you would merge an obstacle with the area polygon if they have no vertice in common (first example). (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Maybe I should go for a Delaunay triangulation instead ? It seems to accept holes in the poly

Comment: You would connect the obstacle square/poly with the surrounding arena poly, by drawing two lines, one from an arena corner A to an obstacle corner B, and one from that same corner B back to the same arena corner A, hence merging the two polys into one. It would have two vertexes on top of each other, but that shouldn't be a problem, just keep track of the line segment's direction, to be able to skip the bad line of them when testing for opposite vertexes in the HM partition. Ofc cut the arena poly where this happens. Same with next obstacle, "bridge" to a nearby arena poly vertex.

Comment: So I should track those "fake edges" to re-link vertices that are on them after triangulation (not sure to be clear - I mean it will be seen as an obstacle in the node graph, so I should correct it)

Comment: Maybe just construct a parallel data set? Something like: Define an approximate "game arena centerpoint" or "chunk centerpoint". For each obstacle, define a centerpoint. For each obstacle, calc the distacne to the arena centerpoint. Sort them so the biggest distance is first. Loop through them all, each time connecting to *what is so far the arena poly*. Ie. the arena poly grows, and obstacles may in fact be connected to (former) obstacles. In the end, you have one single poly *in parallel data only*. Apply HM on that to partition into convex polys, use the convex poly set for pathfinding?

Comment: The only criterion being that a "connect" does not run over an obstacle. In fact, connecting to a closest-by obstacle should work as well, since eventually (even if all obstacles were connected to other obstacles but none to the arena) the last obstacle *will* be connected to the arena (as you'd loop through them all). To be more exact re. the "share vertices" i wrote earlier: They would not share a single vertex, only share the same *location*, but still be separate vertexes (as one is "earlier" in the big poly, the other "later"). In the end, there would be a dataset with convex polys.

Comment: Yep, I get it ! Could you complete the answer for future reference and so I can give you the bounty ? Many thanks for your time and help !

Comment: Looking into this soon, solved the triangulation already, using a "sweep over" method. I'll edit the answer instead of explaining it in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, if you are creating a voxel mesh up 2D, you should create a class that takes a 2D position (Vector2), and one byte (0-255).
Every position, there is a value from 0 to 1, and there is a function in the script the AI that makes it surround a position, and a script that do it an interaction between the positions of enemies and items from the list, and when are with a distance, I know it, 10, it calls the function or void AI and passes the corresponding position.